# Laravel api routes with auth

Tags: ajax, laravel, xmlhttprequest, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to make an api route that's only accessible if the user making the request is logged in. This is what I have in my `routes/api.php` but it returns
`{"error":"Unauthenticated."}`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api'], function () {
    Route::post('schedules', ['uses' => 'Api\ScheduleController@store']);
});
```

Can this be done without laravel passport and how? I only need the route for in-app use for logged in users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assumed the login mentioned is on "web" which using "session" as driver.

Your are getting this issue because "web" and "api" guard is using different driver for authentication. Take a look in `config/auth.php`. The "api" guard is using "token" as it's default driver.

Thus, you have few options to encounter this.

1. Move the route for "schedules" in web.php. No worry, your ajax will failed if not authenticated. But, take note that anything that involved POST method will require **csrf** (`_token` parameter), unless you are using laravel axios
2. Using authentication using api also which you can refer [this tutorial](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51) for "token" driver and all your secure routes will be using token in its **Authentication** header

Comment: I ended up using [JWT](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) but I guess this answers the question (Need to implement token driver). It's weird how Laravel has `token` as default driver in `config/auth.php guards->api` but documentation doesn't even have 1 word written about how to use it.