# How to pass Auth::id() to the controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a payments controller but when I do `dd` of the authenticated `user`, it returns `null`.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Casefile;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Payment;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function apiPaymentByUserId(Request $request) {
        $date_from = $request->$date_from;
        $date_to = $request->$date_to;

        $idAuthenticated = Auth::id();

        DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();

        $payments = DB::table("payments")
                        ->join('casefiles', 'casefiles.id','=', 'payments.casefile_id')
                        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'casefiles.user_id')
                        ->select("payments.*")
                        ->where("payments.created_at", ">=", $date_from)
                        ->where("payments.created_at", "<=", $date_to)
                        ->where("casefiles.user_id", "=", $idAuthenticated)
                        ->get();

        // @dd(DB::getQueryLog());

        @dd($idAuthenticated);
     
        return response()->json([ 
            'success' => true, 
            'response' => $payments 
        ]);
    }
}
```

I need the `auth id` in the last `where` clause but it returns `null`.

What am I missing? Should I copy and paste more code to be more clearer? The route's action where I get parameters is `POST`.

Comment: Which guard you are using for authentication ? or are you using any service provider for tokenization? Like JWT or Passport?

Comment: @MuditGulgulia i'm using the laravel default guard

Comment: How are you registering user sessions on login API in laravel ? using Auth::attempt($cred); or something else ?

Comment: @MuditGulgulia the registering page is made using this command: php artisan ui bootstrap --auth , just this without modifing it for the moment.

Comment: Try using `$idAuthenticated  = Auth::user()->id` to get the id of the current user

Comment: @jptl431 using this i get this error instead of null: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: @Aogiri14 As you mentioned `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` Generating authentication for web app BUT For the API Authentication is different. Like api_token used or someting

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya OK thank you i think as you all mentioned i will implement a token authentication.

Comment: @Aogiri14 see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861937/laravel-api-routes-with-auth) answer for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `id` like this:

```
$idAuthenticated = Auth::user()->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can get auth values like this:

```
$idAuthenticated = Auth::user()->id;
$username = Auth::user()->name;
$email = Auth::user()->email;
```

Or

```
$user = findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an API request, if your default auth guard's config isn't `API`, you must assign the guard like: `auth('api')->user()->id;`.